# How to make S3 serve the same file using http and https in a rails app?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ssl, https, amazon-ec2, amazon-s3

I have an rails application running in Amazon EC2 and with files served in S3.

My problem is: All my application in running normally in http and I'd like to put on https. But, it's a pre-requisite that the same file responds either to http and https.

For example: if I have a file `http://domain.s3.amazon.com/file.js`, it should be respond to `https://domain.s3.amazon.com/file.js` as well.

My scripts will be used by other customers in http and https environments, so it's mandatory that its served as http and https, otherwise the browser will give this message:

`[blocked] The page at 'https://mycustomerurl' was loaded over HTTPS, but ran insecure content from 'http://mydomain.com/myfile.js': this content should also be loaded over HTTPS.`

How can I do that?

Thanks

PS: I've seen some samples, but the whole app goes to https, and I have this specific requisite

Answer (score 0):

As long as the domain is the same, the easiest way to do this is to drop the protocol at the beginning of the url.

Just do a request for `//domain.s3.amazon.com/file.js`

Comment: But this it not my problem: My problem is that i'm serving .js files and its mandatory that the same file responds to http and https request. My scripts will be used by other clients in http and https environments

Comment: If they do a request for the script without the protocol, it will use the current protocol of the page. This works as long as the http domain is the same as the https domain.

Comment: `<script src="//domain.s3.amazon.com/file.js"></script>`

Comment: But look at this [link](http://www.ledface.com/assets/jquery-aaba7df15741e77437ec7e0b979eef9d.js) for instance. If you try this, you're redirected to https version. That's what i'm trying to avoid

Answer (score 0):

I finally found a solution.

At the end, it was not an issue to be solved at application level but at server configuration level.

I've bought a certificate and installed in my server. Then I configured nginx with:

```
worker_processes 1;
http {
server {
listen 443;
ssl on;
ssl_certificate /usr/local/nginx/conf/cert.pem;
ssl_certificate_key /usr/local/nginx/conf/cert.key;
keepalive_timeout 70;
}
}
```